# Hello World - Clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Beginner here.

Can I compile an existing **Clojure** script to run it on the web using **ClojureScript**?

Let's say that I have a script that prints `Hello world` in my terminal, and I want to print that text on the browser. Should I rewrite a whole script with ClojureScript syntax, or should I just compile it using another compiler?

```
(ns clojure-hello-world.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "Hello World"))
```

Comment: (Short answer) You should rewrite the code you posted to avoid using Clojure only features and constructs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Long answer :P)

Even though **Clojure** and **ClojureScript** share a good amount of features, there are some that are specific to one or the other. For example there are no real classes in JavaScript so the `:gen-class` specification in the `ns` form doesn't make much sense.

One important fact is that the **syntax** of both **Clojure** and **ClojureScript** is exactly the same, differences have to do mostly with the host VM in which they run (Java VM in the case of Clojure and JavaScript VM in the case of ClojureScript).

There is a list of the differences between the two Clojure implementations [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure#compilation-and-class-generation).

There's also a tool called [cljx](https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx) to "*write a portable codebase targeting Clojure/ClojureScript*". Recently there has been some [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/clojure-dev/6pnIeXFRwnI) on the [Clojure Dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/clojure-dev) group around finally implementing [feature expressions](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Feature+Expressions) which would on one hand deprecate the use of **cljx** but on the other complicate the work that tools have to do to extract information from Clojure source files.

Answer (score 3):

I would start with [lein-cljsbuild](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild) to get started. This will get you going with a nice edit eval and look at browser loop. It's well worth getting this setup first because it makes learning ClojureScript *much* more fun. I promise it's worth the hassle. If you need more interactive support the folks in #clojure on freenode are very kind and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the Browser executes JavaScript.  You compile your ClojureScript code to JavaScript.  The Browser loads your JavaScript via an HTML page.  So, you have to create an HTML Page and point your Browser at it.

The simplest way I got started was to use Luminous (http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/clojurescript.md).

However, Chestnut (https://github.com/plexus/chestnut) looks promising.